# biblio2yaml is not being installed with pandoc-citeproc. How to install it?

Tags: installation, pandoc, bibliography

Despite of being able to install from pandoc-citeproc from pacman on a Manjaro system, there is not biblio2yaml binary packaged with it. I have tried also from caball and nix package manager and I get the same result. I'm using pandoc-citeproc 0.3.0.1. There is any new way to get biblio2yaml that I'm unaware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [release notes of pandoc-citeproc 0.3](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/ilNH-bmiOOk/lH9Ivsn1NncJ) say:

> Note that the biblio2yaml utility has been removed from pandoc-citeproc.
>   One can now use pandoc-citeproc itself, with the --bib2yaml or --bib2csl
>   option, to convert a bibliography to pandoc YAML metadata or CSL JSON
>   form.

Comment: Thanks Rintze. That's answers my question. (I don't know hot to mark a question as answered). Now I have another problem related with encoding, but that would be for another question :-).

Comment: Also, the pandoc-discuss mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss is quite active, and might be a better location to ask for support than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well I would go for Stack Overflow first and community list second. The ratio information/noise is lower here, when you're looking for particular answers specially for list with hight trafic. Of course Pandoc is a great tool and once I do more with it I can be also a more active member of its community.